# Informatica Cloud Incremental Load

Tags: informatica

guys.

I'm needing create a mapping to do incremental loads in informatica cloud. I know that I can do that with parameter files and using the $Lastruntinme. But, if i use FF as parameters, those parameters can be deleted. Using the $Lastruntime i could have temporal gaps into the target.

Is there other ways to do incremental loads? Maybe using loockup, or a way to use two sources in the same mapping, one reading the last written data and the second source reading the the source data; after that, compare both and get the last.

Answer (score 2):

Any mechanism that reliably allows you to identify which records in your source need to be loaded into your target could be used to build an incremental etl load - but without knowing your data it is impossible for anyone to tell you what would work for you.

You also need to distinguish what would work in principle and what would work in practice. For example, comparing your source and target datasets might work with small datasets but would quickly become impractical as the size of either dataset grew

Comment: To add to this, yes, you can use $lastRunDt kind of parameter but store it somewhere permanent table/file that is secure.  Assuming, RDB, most sources has last update date or something you can use to compare above parameter.  Comparing two tables is the last option because its performance intensive.  Sometime some source can give you change log - which make detection of new record easy - like oracle MV log.

Comment: Thank you, guys, for answer here. I agree with you. I just did this question with the finality to find other ways to do that. Currently, i use a table view in BigQuery to get de most recent date, create a FF parameter with this date and just get source data bigger than parameter date. I know that i have to understand my data to create the better mechanism. I tried everything and now i'm without ideas. thanks guys, @NickW. If you know more options, i'm grateful if you share with me.